# Find identifiers in a java source file

Tags: java

I have the following assignment:

Write a program that reads a Java source file and produces an index of all identifiers in the file. For each identifier, print all lines in which it occurs. Call in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9_]+").  Then each call to next returns a string consisting only of letters, numbers, and underscores.

My plan was to create a sample .java file, and read it in line by line. I'm not sure what is meant by an identifier, or what class has the useDelimiter method mentioned. Can anyone get me off on the right track? Thanks. I would use the homework tag, but it says that it is being removed.

Here is what I have so far. I can get it to print out all of the identifiers in the file, but how can I find out what line number the identifier is on?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the path to your JAVA source file: ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String pathToFile = null;
    try {
        pathToFile = br.readLine();
        File f = new File(pathToFile);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        s.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9_]+");
        while (s.hasNext()) {                     
            String identifier = s.next();
            System.out.println(identifier);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to locate file. Program will exit.\n"
                           + ioe.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This assignment could be described as "print everything that looks like an identifier", because the algorithm it describes will pick up words that are commented out, enclosed in quoted strings, and so on. An *identifier*, at least in Java sense, is a fancy way to say "a string that starts in a letter and consists only of letters, digits, and underscores". Actually, you can use the dollar sign `$` in Java identifiers ([link](http://ideone.com/5Qikv9)), but I suspect your professor would not believe you if you tell him that ;-)

Comment: An identifier is the name given by compiler and language writers to the strings used as the names of variables, types and classes. Java identifiers match the regular expression you have posted.

Comment: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter\(java.lang.String\)) has such method.

Comment: It seems like when I iterate over the lines in the file, I am also getting the empty lines, and lines consisting of just { characters.

Comment: Also, when it says identifier, I'm not sure how to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use:

- [java.io.StreamTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) to filter comments
- [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to filter the token which matches [*A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9*]*